# BBC iPlayer error "A Problem Occurred While Downloading This Programme"

Tags: 11.04, adobe-air, streaming

I'm using BBC iPlayer Desktop v.3.0.10 with Adobe Air v.2.6.0 on Ubuntu 11.04 'Natty Narwhal' Beta 1 86x on a Dell Inspiron 1525

No matter what programme I attempt to download I will get the message "A problem occurred while downloading this programme."

I thought I had fixed the problem when I followed the instructions on the below link under the "Troubleshooting GnomeKeyring" section however this doesn't stick after logging out

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/492/cpsid_49267.html

So any ideas?

I've asked on the Official Iplayer Message Board's and have also emailed the BBC and tweeted to them but as of yet haven't heard anything back about the problem.

Here's a copy of the "iplayer.log" file:
http://pastebin.com/0H4s6R0x

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you download `get-iplayer`, which is better than the BBC's own iPlayer Desktop.

Essentially get-iplayer allows you to download whole TV and radio programmes from the BBC  's server without a limit being imposed on how long you get to view or listen to the content; what you have downloaded you can use forever.

Here's how to install it.

1: In a terminal, run the following (type it in and press `Enter`).

```
sudo apt-get install get-iplayer
```

Type in your password and then press `Enter`. The software will be installed.

2: (In the terminal session) refresh the cached list of programs.

```
get-iplayer --refresh
```

3: Search for (e.g.) a TV program you want to view.

```
get-iplayer 'top gear'
```

4: Download the program.

```
get-iplayer -g 784
```

Comment: These instructions are imcomplete. Can you please edit them to be more explicit?